# Genus $1$ curve over $\Bbb{F}_q$ always has rational points, exercise $10.6$ in Silverman

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, curves, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I want to understand the proof of the fact

> Genus $1$ curve over $\Bbb{F}_q$ always have rational points

The result was originally proven by F.K. Schmidt and is currently presented as Exercise $10.6$ in Silverman's 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves'.

Let $C/\Bbb{F}_q$ be an arbitrary genus $1$ curve.
$C/\overline{\Bbb{F}_q}$ can be regarded as an elliptic curve because it has rational point.

Let $\phi:C\to C$ be the $q$-th power Frobenius map on $C$.

I want to prove that

> There are an endomorphism $f\in End(C)$ and a point $P_0\in C(\overline{\Bbb{F}_q})$ satisfying $\phi(P)=f(P)+P_0$ and there exits a point $P_1 \in C(\overline{\Bbb{F}_q})$ such that $(1-f)(P_1)=P_0$.

If we could prove this, $\phi(P_1)=P_1$ and hence that $P_1\in C(\Bbb{F}_q)$.
Thus $C$ turns out to be an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{F}_q$ and we are done　■

But how can we take $f, P_1 and  P_0$ ?

P.S.
Thanks to comments, $P_0$ is base point and $f(P)=\phi(P)-\phi(P_0)$.

$P_0$　is the only problem.

Comment: $f$ is just a translation (with respect to $P_0$) of $\phi$ in order to make $f$ an endomorfism; i.e. we have a fixed $0\in C(\overline{\mathbb F}_q)$, which plays the role of the zero point, and we only need $f(0)=0$; so $P_0=-\phi(0)$, and $f$ as defined.

Comment: And $P_1$ exists once you know that $f$ is inseparable: this is the key point of the result (proving inseparability of $f$).

Comment: @Nulhomologous Thank you very much. I try to prove inseparability of $f$. Could you tell me why inseparability of $f$ ensures the existence of $P_1$ ?

Comment: If $f$ is purely inseparable, then $1-f$ is separable, hence any point has at least a preimage (since we are over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: And $f$ is purely inseparable because it is the Frobenius (essentially).  Look at Silverman's book where he proves that the Frobenius is inseparable.

Comment: @Nulhomologous, I'm still unclear as to why 1− needs to be separable. An isogeny is surjective over an algebraically closed field, so even without the condition that 1− is separable, I believe every point has a pre-image under 1−.

Comment: @Nulhomologous, we just need to prove $1-f$ is not constant. $(1-f)(P)=P-f(P)=P-\phi(P)+\phi(P_0)≠P$.

Comment: @Nulhomologous I think to prove separability of $1-f$ is overthinking, isn't it ?

Comment: Of course you need to show $1-f$ is not constant, i.e. $f$ is not the identity, i.e. $\phi$ is not constant,, which is clear.

Comment: It seems you are right and you don't really need separability (contrary to what Silverman's says in the book).